# GIWS terminate process while constructing class

Tags: java, c++, xml, latex

Since I could not find a proper library in C++ in order to use for rendering images from TeX, without dependency of LaTeX, I made up my mind to use GIWS. I also tried mimeTeX but I could not find it enough for my project (it does not easily work with C++, and rendered images are not good, moreover .gif not .png)
This is my Java Code:

```
package clatex;

import java.io.IOException;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXConstants;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXFormula;
import org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath.TeXIcon;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class CLatex {
    public CLatex(){

    }

    public int turn(int a) throws IOException{
        String math = "X+X";

        TeXFormula formule = new TeXFormula(math);
        TeXIcon ti = formule.createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 40);
        BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(ti.getIconWidth(), ti.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);

        File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
        ImageIO.write(b, "png", outputfile);
        return 0;
    }
}`
```

To summarize this code: I have a package called clatex, I'm using org.scilab.forge.jlatexmath. The method int turn() creates "saved.png" and the constructor is empty. I also tested this code.
This is CLatex.giws.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<package name="CLatex">
  <object name="CLatex">
      <method name="turn" returnType="int">
        <param type="int" name="a" />
      </method>
  </object>
</package>
```

This code is relevant with GIWS.
GIWS renders this code and generates CLatex.cpp and CLatex.h. This is my C++ code:

```
#include "latex/CLatex.h"
#include <jni.h>
JavaVM* create_vm() {
    JavaVM* jvm; JNIEnv* env;

    JavaVMInitArgs args;
    JavaVMOption options[2];

    /* There is a new JNI_VERSION_1_4, but it doesn't add anything for the purposes of our example. */
    args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;

    args.nOptions = 2;
    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";

    options[1].optionString = "-Xcheck:jni";
    args.options = options;

    args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

    JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &args);

    return jvm;
}

int main(){
    JavaVM* jvm = create_vm();

    CLatex::CLatex *test =
    new CLatex::CLatex(jvm);

    return test->turn(22);
}
```

When I use this code, it writes: "Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)". It does not compile and gives error.
I do not know which part of my code is wrong, Java, XML or C++ (Maybe something is wrong with GIWS?). I'm unfortunately not good at Java, but trying to get handle it. Thank you for your help.
As a note, I use Code::Blocks with GCC for C++; and NetBeans for Java, under Ubuntu Quantal Quetzal.

Comment: I understood that something is wrong with CLatex.cpp, and this file is created by GIWS (I did not touch it at all) In order to detect it it put exit(88) to various places in this file (88 is just a random debug int) It turns 1 (not 88!) when I put this control AFTER "return curEnv;" in CLatex.cpp (it's in 54. line, under JNIEnv * CLatex::getCurrentEnv() method)
And when compiler is compiling this code, nothing is wrong, the problem occurs when compiler links the object files.
I thus assume there is a bug in GIWS (I even tried the original example)

Answer (score 1):

I added an example on how to call `JLaTeXMath` from C++ in using `GIWS` wrapper in the git repository:
http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/jlatexmath/source/tree/master/examples/GIWS

Answer (score 0):

GIWS generates C++ code. Therefor, I don't see how you can get CLatex.h.

Tell which version of GIWS you are using would help too.

Finally, you should use a debugger to see what is going on.